# hci0 not detected in dmesg in distros other than Debian

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, firmware, dmesg, realtek

I tried ubuntu,pop os, elementary, bluetooth worked on none of them. In the bluetooth settings, it said no adapters found or no device found. When I installed debian, placed the rtl_bt folder in /lib/firmware/ and did modprobe -r btusb and then modprobe btusb, bluetooth started working, when I repeated the same steps on other distros, it did not work. In "dmesg | grep Blue" on debian, I see the lines with hci0 device, this hci0 is not seen in dmesg of any other distro than [image: Screenshot] debian. I will add the screenshot of dmesg fron debian. Can anybody tell what is going on?